# How to make measures (regular/loaded) invisible?

Tags: mdx, olap, iccube

As of icCube 4 it is possible to **hide** calculated members, but still available for other calculations as input.

How can I make loaded measures invisible - if at all?

I have allready tried adding cellproperties: VISIBLE = 0

Thanks in advance,

Arthur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can play with the visibility of MDX entities in the perspectives use case, [online doc](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/schemas_cubes/adv_perspectives.html)